# The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found in springboot

Tags: java, web-services, file-upload, spring-boot, multifile-uploader

As I am trying this with spring boot and webservices with postman chrome add-ons.

In postman `content-type="multipart/form-data"` and I am getting the below exception.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; 
nested exception is java.io.IOException: 
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

In Controller I specified the below code

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", headers = "Content-Type= multipart/form-data", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String upload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam(value = "file", required = true) MultipartFile file)
//@RequestParam ()CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload
{
    // @RequestMapping(value="/newDocument", , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] fileContent = file.getBytes();
            fileSystemHandler.create(123, fileContent, name);
            return "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

Here I specify the file handler code

```
public String create(int jonId, byte[] fileContent, String name) {
    String status = "Created file...";
    try {
        String path = env.getProperty("file.uploadPath") + name;
        File newFile = new File(path);
        newFile.createNewFile();
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile));
        stream.write(fileContent);
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        status = "Failed to create file...";
        Logger.getLogger(FileSystemHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: I also facing the same problem, and its only work in postman not working with other tools like "Advance rest client". may I know why??

Comment: @Narendhran, we can upload files from ARC now, which will eliminate this problem. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59342761/3519504

Answer (score 163):

The problem is that you are setting the `Content-Type` by yourself, let it be blank. Google Chrome will do it for you. The multipart `Content-Type` needs to know the file boundary, and when you remove the `Content-Type`, Postman will do it automagically for you.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me in Postman. Also, answer from tomeokin helps in the sens that, Postman is not suitable for all test scenarios.

Comment: when i remove content-type, i am getting this
"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain' not supported"

Comment: When I remove the Content-Type header, the server does not receive the data parameter (which is the payload).

Comment: Perhaps Postman changed the way he handles it since 2016

Comment: Thanks! It's solved my problem!

Answer (score 27):

Unchecked the content type in Postman and postman automatically detect the content type based on your input in the run time.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me:
Uploading a file via Postman, to a SpringMVC backend webapp:

Backend:
[image: Endpoint controller definition]

Postman:
[image: Headers setup]
[image: POST Body setup]

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem while making a POST request from Postman and later I could solve the problem by setting a custom Content-Type with a boundary value set along with it like this.

I thought people can run into similar problem and hence, I'm sharing my solution.

[image: postman]

Comment: How did u get the boundary value?

Comment: The boundary value was suggested in the API doc.

Answer (score 1):

Heard you can do this in postman:

[image: placeholders]

Answer (score 0):

The "Postman - REST Client" is not suitable for doing post action with setting content-type.You can try to use "Advanced REST client" or others.

Additionally, headers was replace by consumes and produces since Spring 3.1 M2, see https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/13/spring-3-1-m2-spring-mvc-enhancements. And you can directly use `produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`.

Comment: This is really helpful answer. It solved my problem. With Advanced REST client, I am able to send the same request which I was trying with Postman. Postman requests were resulting in an errors `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found` and `HTTP 405`

Answer (score 0):

When I use postman to send a file which is 5.6M to an external network,  I faced the same issue. The same action is succeeded on my own computer and local testing environment.

After checking all the server configs and HTTP headers, I found that the reason is Postman may have some trouble simulating requests to external HTTP requests.
Finally, I did the sendfile request on the chrome HTML page successfully.
Just as a reference :)

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem because I use request.js which writen base on axios
And I already set a defaults.headers in request.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
const request = axios.create({
  baseURL: '', 
  timeout: 15000 
})
service.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

here is how I solve this
instead of

```
request.post('/manage/product/upload.do',
      param,config
    )
```

I use axios directly send request,and didn't add config

```
axios.post('/manage/product/upload.do',
      param
    )
```

hope this can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below simple code, it should work. I tested on Advanced REST Client and below attached screenshot will help for configuration.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RestController
public class ImageUploadController {

    @PostMapping("image-upload")
    public String uploadImage(@RequestParam MultipartFile myFile) throws IOException {
        
        byte[] bytes = myFile.getBytes();

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("image.jpg");

        fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        
        return "Image uploaded successfully..!";

    }
}
```

[image]

you can find uploaded image on below location in project.

[image]

Also please note that if your controller should be within the package of @SpringBootApplication package. You can refer below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to send `Content-Type` in Postman, leave the default setting as in `Headers` section. It should automatically calculate.
[image]

In Body, you can select file as:
[image]

At Spring controller side, you can add following code:

```
 @PostMapping("/upload")  
 public ResponseEntity<MyResponseObject> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile myFile)
  throws IOException {...}
```