# Uploading a file using fetch and formdata succeeds in Ubuntu but failed in Windows 10

Tags: javascript, windows, ubuntu, fetch, multipartform-data

guys. I met a annoying issue these days.

I am trying to upload a file to the server side using fetch in FormData type as follows:

```
export function buildFormData(request) {
  const formData = new window.FormData();
  for (const name in request) {
    formData.append(name, request[name]);
  }
  return formData;
}
```

and then

```
export function checkImported(file) {
  const formData = UTILS.buildFormData({ file });
  return fetch(`${ServerConst.SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH}/import/check`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  }).then(response => response.json());
}
```

In **Ubuntu** the request is:

[image]

In **Windows 10** is:

[image]

All I checked differently is the **Request Payload** which is **text/csv** in Ubuntu while **application/octet-stream** in Windows 10;

But when I tried to add **headers** for the **fetch** as follows:

```
export function checkImported(file) {
  const formData = UTILS.buildFormData({ file });
  return fetch(`${ServerConst.SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH}/import/check`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; text/csv' },
    body: formData,
  }).then(response => response.json());
}
```

, it will failed in ubuntu also (the server side will prompt me about `the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`. And the reason is explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005436/the-request-was-rejected-because-no-multipart-boundary-was-found-in-springboot/38013585) clearly.

Can anyone help? Thank you very much!

Best wishes, Hearen.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the backend validation in java which will filter out other types retaining only the "Content-Type: text/csv".

As you can see that in windows, the Content-Type in `Request Payload` is *application/octet-stream*.

Since the frontend can filter out all non-csv files via `accept` in upload, I removed the validation in backend and solved the problem.