# Upload file with JSON data in Angular5 and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, angular5, multipartform-data, form-data

I am stuck in getting the request at my REST Controller.
Below is my Controller method :

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
    public UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/fileUploadApi",  consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody StatusUpload fileUpload(@RequestPart("uploadfile") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("user") User userDto) throws Exception{
        StatusUpload status= new StatusUpload();
        status = userService.callUserServiceForFileRead(file, userDto);
        return status;
    }
```

In ApplicationConfig.java, I added the following :

```
@Bean
     public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
         CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
         multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000000);
         return multipartResolver;
     }
```

Below is the code I have written for file upload at Angular5 end:

HTML:

```
    <!-- Other form elements -->
    <!-- Used PrimeNG Custom Upload Handler to get the File Object https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload -->
        <label>Upload template </label>
          <p-fileUpload (uploadHandler)="getFile($event)" auto="true" customUpload="true"  accept=".xlsx,application/msexcel"  previewWidth="0" [showUploadButton]="false" [showCancelButton]="false">
          </p-fileUpload>
<!-- Form Submit Button -->
<button type="button" (click)="submit()">SUBMIT</button>
```

COMPONENT :

```
    user: User = new User;
// Set other form element data in user object.
    uploadFile: File;
    getFile(event) {
        this.uploadfile= event.files[0];
      }
submit() {
    this.userService.saveUserData(this.user,this.uploadFile);

  }
```

SERVICE :

```
options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({  'Content-Type': ''  })
  };
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    saveUserData(user:User, uploadFile:File){
    var formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('user',JSON.stringify(user));
    formData.append('uploadfile',uploadFile);
    return this.http.post<StatusUpload>(baseUrl + "/fileUploadApi", formData, this.options);
    }
```

When I use the above Service, it gives me no response/no Exception don't know why. The request even didn't reach my RESTController.
I read a different approach in some post & used it as below :

```
saveUserData(user: User, uploadFile: File) {
var formData: FormData = new FormData();
Observable.fromPromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  formData.append('user', new Blob([JSON.stringify(user)],
    {
      type: "application/json"
    }));
  formData.append('uploadfile', uploadFile);
  xhr.open("POST", baseUrl + "/fileUploadApi", true);
  xhr.send(formData);
}));
}
```

With above, I get org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException.

Can anyone please help to get this code working. I need to use the http.post() in my Angular service, not the XMLHttpRequest.send() one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the observable.

> An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true for all HttpClient methods.

[Docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#always-subscribe)

Comment: I can't believe I made this mistake.. Thanks for identifying it.. It then says, Content Type cannot be ' ', HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.. Can you please help what exactly should be the Content Type for the HTTP post here.

Comment: application/json gives org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported...
If I remove the Content Type as suggested here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005436/the-request-was-rejected-because-no-multipart-boundary-was-found-in-springboot , it gives org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'uploadfile' is not present..

Comment: 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' gives org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found