# the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found java

Tags: java, spring, file

I am developing a file upload functionality. for that I have a spring boot web service and client is angular.

**Webservice:-**

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/sendmails", headers = "content-type=multipart/*", consumes = "application/*")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendEmails(@RequestParam("data") MultipartFile reapExcelDataFile) {
    
        return new ResponseEntity("Success", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**UI: -**

```
postFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<boolean> {
  const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8080/sendmails';
debugger;
  let config =  {headers: new  HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})};
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('data', fileToUpload);
  return this.httpClient.post(endpoint, formData, config)
    .pipe(map(() => { return true; }));
}
```

**ERROR: -**

> 2020-07-31 16:13:19.644 ERROR 13144 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse
> multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException:
> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the
> request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found] with
> root cause
>
> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the
> request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found  at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.(FileUploadBase.java:834)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2881)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3214)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1116)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:84)
> ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
> ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
> ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
> ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]     at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]     at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]     at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]     at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]     at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]     at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> [na:1.8.0_251]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> [na:1.8.0_251]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]     at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_251]

If I remove the file and give a string then the call is going. What might be the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005436/the-request-was-rejected-because-no-multipart-boundary-was-found-in-springboot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found in springboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005436/the-request-was-rejected-because-no-multipart-boundary-was-found-in-springboot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I am setting the `Content-Type` by myself, let it be blank. Google Chrome will do it for me. The multipart `Content-Type` needs to know the file boundary, and when you remove the `Content-Type`, Postman will do it automagically for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 15+ with restful spring api, I did encapsulated the file in ***FormData*** object and it worked :

```
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("file", file, file.name);

return this.http.post<any>(`${env.apiUrl}/controllerUrl/uploadFile`, formData);
```