# Debugging RESTEasy File Upload - `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request`

Tags: java, file-upload, postman, multipartform-data, resteasy

I am getting the following error when I try to call a webservice at `/upload` to upload a multipart-form data using RESTEasy.

`org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found.`

`/upload` webservice:

```
@POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) {

        String fileName = "";
        
        Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
        List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("uploadedFile");

        for (InputPart inputPart : inputParts) {

         try {

            MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = inputPart.getHeaders();
            fileName = getFileName(header);

            //convert the uploaded file to inputstream
            InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class,null);

            byte [] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
                
            //constructs upload file path
            fileName = UPLOADED_FILE_PATH + fileName;
                
            writeFile(bytes,fileName);
                
            System.out.println("Done");

          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        }

        return Response.status(200)
            .entity("uploadFile is called, Uploaded file name : " + fileName).build();

    }

    /**
     * header sample
     * {
     *  Content-Type=[image/png], 
     *  Content-Disposition=[form-data; name="file"; filename="filename.extension"]
     * }
     **/
    //get uploaded filename, is there a easy way in RESTEasy?
    private String getFileName(MultivaluedMap<String, String> header) {

        String[] contentDisposition = header.getFirst("Content-Disposition").split(";");
        
        for (String filename : contentDisposition) {
            if ((filename.trim().startsWith("filename"))) {

                String[] name = filename.split("=");
                
                String finalFileName = name[1].trim().replaceAll("\"", "");
                return finalFileName;
            }
        }
        return "unknown";
    }
}
```

When I try to debug it with debug points inside the web service, the debug control is not going inside the webservice.

I used Postman with the correct headers to send the request and got the following error as response:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY007500: Could find no Content-Dispostion header within part

To make sure I am looking at the right method in the web service's code, I replaced the entire method with a return statement that returned a 500 Internal Server Error. This meant I should receive a 500 Internal Server error upon calling the /upload endpoint; however, I still received the same error as before.

It appears some other logic is run before the control ever reaches the /upload method, and I can't for the life of me figure out where that's coming from. It might be a decorator of some sort, but I'm not too familiar with Java, so any pointers would be helpful.

**Sidenote:** As I was unsure what was causing this error, I even looked at the [source code for RESTEasy on GitHub](https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy/blob/ab69a05700e6df987d6bf8de00d58fc57263c4fb/providers/multipart/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/multipart/i18n/Messages.java#L27). I figured it has something to do with `Content-Disposition` header not being provided correctly, but I am providing it correctly to the best of my knowledge.

I also tried to provide Content-Disposition header within the multipart form body, but that did not help.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Do you set header Content/type while calling your webservice at /upload? if yes this could be the issue. Maybe your problem is similar to this below issue

[The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found in springboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005436/the-request-was-rejected-because-no-multipart-boundary-was-found-in-springboot)